# NetSuite sublist column order (suitescript 2)

Tags: suitescript2.0

Is there any way to add a sublist field via a user event script and define its column position? By default the field is added as the last column. It appears you can move form fields around, but can't change sublist column order.

Answer (score 0):

We can able to edit sublist column postion.

But it can be vary based on your records either transaction or suitlet script or any other things just elaborate your question pls.

Comment: Attempting to add a column to an existing transaction record's sublist via a UE script in edit mode

Answer (score 0):

// For This Example we create a first Field
var field1 = form.addField({
    id : 'textfield1',
    type : serverWidget.FieldType.TEXT,
    label : 'Text'
});

// For This Example we create a first Field
var field2 = form.addField({
    id : 'textfield2',
    type : serverWidget.FieldType.TEXT,
    label : 'Text'
});

form.insertField({
    field : field2,
    nextfield : 'textfield1'
});

Comment: Thanks, but that only works for form fields. I'm looking to change the column position of a sublist field.